# Matching strings to data from a file in python

Tags: python

I have a file, it takes the vague form of a table. newlines (`\r\n`) separate rows and tabs (`\t`) separate columns on the rows where there are more than one

I have opened the file and then read it line by line into a list like so:

```
file = open('data.txt')
table = file.readlines()
```

I am now trying to delete certain rows from the file (thus items from the list) that are irrelevant (column headings and such). My attempt looks like this:

```
for i in table:
    if table[i] == "Tue":
        del(table[i])
```

but neither `"Tue"` not `"Tue\r\n"` are matching with the conditional.
I have checked the file in *notepad++* and `Tue\r\n` is all the text on the line.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What about just `"Tue\n"`? Also `for i in table` actually makes `i` a row of the table, so you don't want to reindex with `i`. Anyways, the better idea is to ask if `"Tue"` is `in` the line: `for row in table: ... if "Tue" in row`. For e.g. `"Tue" in "Tuesday"` returns `True`.

Comment: each item in the list tables is a complete line. So, when you have if table[i] == "Tue", what you are checking is if the entire line contains a single word and that word is Tue. You are NOT simply checking if the word Tue exists somewhere in the line. Best to use a regex in this case or something like: if 'Tue' in table[i].

Comment: I don't understand, what do you expect? `'Tue' != "Tue\r\n"`..., furthermore, as an answer has pointed out, you are incorrectly using a `for-loop`. Finally, *don't delete from a list while iterating over it* (unless you are being very careful...)

Comment: Alexander, yeah, my actual code doesn't use `for i in table`, I was just throwing something together for the purpose of the question - my real issue with the matching. I can't use `if "Tue" in i` because while it will remove the lines that say "Tue", it will also remove and other lines with the word "Tuesday" in them which must not happen

Comment: Printing data, variables, calculation results, conditions is a good way to easily see what is happening in your loop ... `for i in table: print(i, table[i]) ...`.  sometimes things aren't what you expect them to be.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga I already found out about iterating over a list whilst editing it - I have implemented a workaround but its nasty - so I just threw in the for loop as an example, the crux of my problem is making the conditional evaluate properly. I am not trying to evaluate "Tue" and "Tue\r\n" together, they are the strings I have tried in the conditional in my code to match what should be their equal in the file

Comment: It helps us if you include a minimal example of the *input* data,. [mcve]

Comment: input data goes like this:

Mon\r\n
Activity    Module    Session    Day\r\n
A15QWR    General    1    Monday\r\n

etc etc

As you can see, the line containing the word monday is important, but the line with just "Mon" is junk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do "for i in table" the i variable is not a counter into the rows it's the actual row of data. If you want the counter, then this works:

```
for i, line in enumerate(table):
```

To deal with any possible newline or trailing whitespace rstrip is helpful:

```
#!/bin/python
file = open('a')
table = file.readlines()
for line in table:
  if line.rstrip() != 'Tue':
    print line
```

But you have to be careful about deleting from table - every time you do everything shifts down, so the current del(table[i]) will fail in mysterious ways.  If you really want to create a new array, this works:

```
#!/bin/python
file = open('a')
table = file.readlines()
table2 = []
for line in table:
  if line.rstrip() != 'Tue':
    table2.append(line.rstrip())

for line in table2:
  print line
```

Which will do something like what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`for i in table` will iterate through the table list, and set i to each member of the list, in your case, a line in the file - a string.

So when your are testing the contents of `table[i]`, you'll probably get an indexing error (btw, you should post your errors :) ).

Test `i` instead of `table[i]` instead.

Comment: Good catch! But also, `'Tue' != "Tue\r\n"`

Comment: To solve the problem @juanpa.arrivillaga states is as simple as checking if "Tue" is in the line instead of if it's equivalent to the line. And maybe it'd be better to give `i` a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the file as a string. Use a CSV library of some kind and operate on lines as records and columns as fields. There are too many special cases to think about, that someone has already solved for you in a library.

`tablib` is one such library, but there are many to consider based on your taste.

Answer (score 0):

Alex actually caught it in the first comment "Tue\n" matches with the document after all. Somewhere along the line the /r must be stripped out.